# Algorithm to pick up moving objects

Tags: ros, moveit, rrt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am a newbie to ROS.

I have a task wherein there is a running conveyor belt with objects on it which have to be picked up a Robotic Arm and placed at some other location all with getting data from a Microsoft Kinect.

I would like to know of some ideas / algorithms that one may use in such a scenario to accomplish this task. Some help with some tools to accomplish this task would also be helpful.

Cheers,
Jalashwa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255837/algorithm-to-pick-up-moving-objects/) by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A team of researches at CMU did this a while back: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~maxim/files/planforsmoothpick_icra14.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Emaxim/files/planforsmoothpick_icra14.pdf) and even got an article in IEEE spectrum about their work: http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/industrial-robots/pr2-learns-pick-and-place-skills-gives-baxter-a-run-for-its-way-less-money

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on 2017-02-28**:
Hi Hendrix, I did spot that research paper a while ago.

Would you recommend me using MoveIt! for my application ?

I'm sorry if I sound a bit stupid :(

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-28**:
I'm not sure; I can't tell from their research paper if they were using MoveIt! or not.